# Want to send a video from desktop to Wowza using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, local, wowza

I am trying to stream a local `.mp4` video file from my laptop to `Wowza Streaming Engine` using ffmpeg. Both systems are able to ping each other. I give the following command on my laptop

```
ffmpeg -re -i bunny_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 48000 -strict experimental -f flv "rtmp://192.168.1.22:1935/live/myStream"
```

`192.168.1.22` is the IP address of Wowza server residing on another system running `Ubuntu 17.04`.

I see the following on the command prompt of my laptop when I give the above command,

```
ffmpeg version N-89894-g18e2ac032e Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  5.101 / 58.  5.101
  libavdevice    58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bunny_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2013-12-16T17:59:32.000000Z
    title           : Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version
    artist          : Blender Foundation 2008, Janus Bager Kristensen 2013
    comment         : Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net
    genre           : Animation
    composer        : Sacha Goedegebure
  Duration: 00:10:34.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4486 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4001 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-16T17:59:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-16T17:59:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 320 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-16T17:59:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
[rtmp @ 000001ed7c4108c0] No credentials set
[rtmp @ 000001ed7c4108c0] Server error: [ AccessManager.Reject ] : [ code=403 need auth; authmod=adobe ] :
rtmp://192.168.1.22:1935/live/myStream: Unknown error occurred
```

Can anyone please tell me what the exact procedure is to stream a video file to Wowza .

How will I be able to view the stream at Wowza ?

Comment: “Code=403 need auth;”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like RTMP authentication for encoders is enabled? In that case you need to either disable it for given live application you are connecting to or provide the credentials.

For the first scenario, remove the authentication as per https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-enable-username-password-authentication-for-rtmp-and-rtsp-publishing

For the second scenario, modify your FFmpeg commandline to incorporate the credentials:

```
ffmpeg -re -i bunny_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 48000 -strict experimental -f flv "rtmp://192.168.1.22:1935/live/myStream flashver=FMLE/3.0\20(compatible;\20FMSc/1.0) live=true pubUser=xxx pubPasswd=yyy"
```

where xxx is user name and yyy is password.

Comment: Yes. I provided my credentials in the url and it worked. The command that I gave was 

ffmpeg -re -i bunny_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 48000 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://username:password@192.168.1.22:1935/live/myStream